# React Native - Cascade state updates from parent to child

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to cascade a state change from a parent component down to a child.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.listUpdater = new_list_updater();

    this.state = {
      schoollist: this.listUpdater.update_list(),
    }
  } 

  listUpdateCallback = () => {
    console.log("Callback triggered!");
    console.log(this.state.schoollist.slice(1,3));
    this.setState({schoollist: this.listUpdater.update_list()});
    console.log(this.state.schoollist.slice(1,3));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Header updateCallback={this.listUpdateCallback}/>
        <SchoolList school_list={this.state.schoollist}/>
      </SafeAreaView>      
    );
  }
}
```

listUpdater.update_list() is a method in a class that implements getISchools and ShuffleArray and stores the list of schools that are being shuffled.  It returns the shuffled list of schools.

```
import { shuffleArray } from './Shuffle'
import { getISchools } from './iSchoolData'

class ListUpdater{
    constructor() {
        console.log("Initiating class!");
        this.currentSchoolList = [];
    }

    update_list() {
        console.log("Updating list!");
        if (this.currentSchoolList.length == 0){
            this.currentSchoolList = getISchools();        
        }
        else{
            shuffleArray(this.currentSchoolList);
        }
        return(this.currentSchoolList);
    }
}

export function new_list_updater(){
    return new ListUpdater();
}
```

As far as I can tell everything works.  When I press a refresh button in the Header component, it triggers the updateCallback, which updates the list stored in the state variable (verified by logging to console and ComponentDidUpdate()

This is the Component not refreshing:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, FlatList } from 'react-native';

export default class SchoolList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.listArea}>
                <FlatList
                data = {this.props.school_list}
                renderItem = {({item}) =>
                    <View style={styles.row}>
                        <View style={styles.num_area}>
                            <Text style={styles.num_text}>{item.key}</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.text_area}>
                            <Text style={styles.univ_text}>{item.univ}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.school_text}>{item.school}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                }
                />
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
        console.log("SchooList Updated!");
    }
}
```

The flow I'm expecting is:

1. Parent passes updateCallback reference to Header (child)
2. Refresh button in Header triggers updateCallback in Parent
3. updateCallback in Parent updates state with setState
4. Parent and relevant children that use state variable re-render, displaying new list

1-3 appear to be working, 4 is not!

Comment: if you add `componentDidUpdate()` lifecycle to `App` and `SchoolList`, does it fire when you click Refresh in `Header`? I made a small example of what you are doing in ReactJS and couldn't reproduce the problem

Comment: @Anthony i added componentDidUpdate() to both App and SchoolList and verified it fires for both when I click the refresh button. 

I added the code for the SchoolList component that isn't refreshing, if that helps

Comment: can you log out `prevProps` and `this.props` in `SchoolList` in `componentDidUpdate()`?

Comment: Thanks - when I log out this.props, it shows that it is updating with the new shuffled list.  I am not sure why it is not re-rendering the Flatlist with the new values

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your componenet is not re-rendering when you use setState for some reason. Try adding a warn in the render method to check this. I also noticed you are mutating the array this.currentSchoolList, winch is passade as reference for your state (all objects are passed as refence). Try replaceing this making a copy of the array beforing calling shuffleArray(this.currentSchoolList).

You can copy the array this way (this is ES6 sintax): newArray = [...oldArrray];
Or using other methods.

Comment: This ended up fixing it!  I thought I could shuffle the original array in place and it would work but perhaps setState didn't update because it was still referencing the original reference?  Not entirely sure - but creating a copy and shuffling that instead and then updating the state with the copy ended up fixing it.

Comment: In React you should never mutate the state directly. React compares the current state with the previous state when you use setState, to know if anything has changed. Probably what happened here is that you mutated the state, and then set it with setState(). So React compared the current mutated state with the new state you passed to setState(), wich will be the same! So, for React, nothing has changed.